# Can I plot 1D heatmap with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a 1D heatmap using two columns of data (x value and y value) in gnuplot. The linegraph plotted using my data is like this:

Linegraph:
[image]

However after some trying I can only achieve this:

What I've got:
[image]

And what I want to get is something like this. (Only example)

What I want:

[image]

The gnuplot script that I use is as follows:

```
set view map
set size ratio 0.2
unset ytics
unset key
splot 'test.dat' u 1:(1):2 palette
```

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
unset key
set xrange noextend
set offset 0,0,graph .05,graph .05
set palette cubehelix negative

plot 'foo.dat' using 0:3 with lines lc "black", \
     'foo.dat' using 0:(70):3 with lines lc palette lw 10
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That is actually what I want.

Comment: I'm glad that solves your problem.  Please mark the answer as "accepted" so that the next person with a similar issue can find it more easily.

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner of stackoverflow and I accept your answer. However, I still don't have a permission to vote yet. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 1):

So you want to use the y axis as a fake dimension in order to increase the width of your second line plot?
Sure, this is e.g. possible with `boxxyerror` with explicit ymin and ymax errors that fill the `yrange`.

```
set xr [-10:10]
set yr [0:1]
xspacing = 0.1
plot '+' u 1:(0.5):($1-xspacing):($1+xspacing):(0):(1):(sin($1)) w boxxyerror lc palette
```

In your case replace the `sin(x)` with the respective column of your data. With the special file `'+'` the x-width has no effect, but in your case you might need to play around with a proper `xspacing` in order to avoid white gaps between the points.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this method works well and I could adjust xspacing for a better look.

Comment: @ShanJ Glad to hear it was helpful! On SO, "thank you" is expressed as accepting the answer and/or upvoting.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply.  I'm a beginner of stackoverflow and still don't have permission to vote. (I'll come back later to do this). And I found that the other answer fits better my need. (Sure your solution is very helpful)